# Gradle - Test tasks results not cached

Tags: java, gradle, caching

"Test" tasks in my multi-module build are not being cached by Gradle. Incremental build works fine and reports everything as up-to-date, but if I perform clean build tests are always executed.

I am seeing this message `Non-cacheable because 'Task outputs cacheable' not satisfied [ENABLE_CONDITION_NOT_SATISFIED]` for all the **test** tasks if `org.gradle.caching.debug` parameter set to `true`. All fingerprints are identical between executions.
Any ideas what does it mean and/or how to fix it?

P.S. Using Gradle 6.7 with Junit 5 and JaCoCo. Disabling JaCoCo does not change anything.

Comment: Have you declared any custom outputs on them, or are you using any plugins that might do that?

Comment: @BjørnVester Not something that I am aware of. Plain Junit 5 with JaCoCo. Disabling JaCoCo does not change anything.

Comment: I just tried initializing ("gradle init") a new project with Gradle 6.7.1, chose "app" as the starting template, Java as the implementation language, JUnit 5 as the testing tool and Groovy as the DSL. Then added JaCoCo to all projects and enabled the build cache. Running "clean build" twice in a row makes use of the cache and the tests are not executed again. So there must be something in your build that interferes with it. Maybe you can make a small, reproducible example? Or post some snippets of your build?

Comment: @BjørnVester Unfortunately, it is a big project with a complex build and it will be problematic to create an example. Can you share some pointers on how to check why I am getting the "ENABLE_CONDITION_NOT_SATISFIED" message?

Comment: From what I can tell, it happens when there is a `cacheIf` block that is not satisfied. Of cause that can be anywhere, even in binary plugins. But try searching the code base for it. I don't believe any of the Gradle core plugins uses `cacheIf` by themselves.

Comment: You were correct. I traced the problem to the `com.palantir.baseline-testing` plugin that I missed previously. Not sure why it happens, but removing the plugin fixed tests caching.